# How to redirect app page to fan page in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

I've got a site and setup facebook connect for users to login with facebook, which is working fine. now if I type my app url in browser it opens nothing but blank page with facebook logo etc. I want to show users fan page when they type apps address. like when we type http://apps.facebook.com/uno then it shows us their fan page http://www.facebook.com/uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use top.location.href, this should redirect the page within Facebook.

Ex: top.location.href = "apps.facebook.com/yourappid"

Comment: Well, are you running a javascript script for the page? Put it in there. You should have an HTML for the page that looks like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "apps.facebook.com/yourappid"
</script>

Comment: I can edit only scripts in my site but not of the facebook fan page or facebook app. I am using app only for users to register and login to my site. how can i show the fan page from app address in browser.maybe put fan page url in canvas address bar or callback url. what?

Comment: I m not talking about an app running on my own server. this is facebook app and i have a facebook app page. facebook limits to edit them. or if I can, then how?

Comment: Honestly, not sure. You'll just have to play around with it. I have no idea what tools they give you or anything.

Comment: OK what i have done that i have created a.html file in my website root and added 
<script>
top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/my app?sk=app_appid' 
</script>, in my canvas url i entered http://mysite.com/a.html?ref=abc and in secure canvas url i entered https://bit.ly/mysite_a[dot]html because i dont use https yet

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the html of the page?  If so, try something like this:

```
<p><META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; URL=http://www.facebook.com/uno"></p>
```

It will redirect the browser to the fan page.

Comment: I don't think facebook gives you base-level access to the HTML of your app/fan pages.